# Match cases i diffrent colums MS excel

Tags: excel

[example data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3GKaR.gif)

I have four columns of data, two of these are names (A and D). One (B) is total work hours, and one (E) is time in training.

Can I write a function which does this:
Writes the value of column E in column C in the *right* place, i.e. "41" in row 2, "32.8" in row 5 and "24.6" in row 8.

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

i just quickly put something together, but it works, you may need to tweak it to use your sheet name etc....

```
Private Sub FindNames()
Dim RngArr As Variant
Dim i As Long, j As Long
Dim Rws As Long
Dim FRw As Long

'Sheet1 here is not the tab name, but the CodeName (in VBA its the name not in brackets in project explorer)
RngArr = Sheet1.UsedRange.Value 'get range array

If Not IsArray(RngArr) Then Exit Sub    'either a single cell is used or something is wrong

FRw = Sheet1.UsedRange.Row
Rws = UBound(RngArr, 1) - 1           'get total rows in range minus 1

For i = FRw To FRw + Rws        'loop for the list in D:E
    If Not RngArr(i, 4) = vbnulstring Then
        For j = FRw To FRw + Rws    'loop for the list in A:B (C)
            'if ColD = ColA then ColC = ColE
            If RngArr(i, 4) = RngArr(j, 1) Then RngArr(j, 3) = RngArr(i, 5)
        Next j
    Else
        'you could exit the loop here if you list will never have empty spaces to save time although you wont notice
    End If
Next i

Sheet1.UsedRange.Value = RngArr 'since we are resizing the original used space we can just dump the results back
```

End Sub

Hope this helps
Paul S.